# how to make an image title array

Tags: php, arrays, input, textbox, gallery

I am using the following code to populate images from MySQL database. I want to have image_title for every image which will be a textbox below the image. I know how to populate it but how can I make it named so when user changes the title it will only change for the specific image?

```
<?php
    $mysql_command = "CALL sp_populate_member_article_media(:param_article_guid, :param_member_id)";
    $mysql_query = $mysql_connection->prepare($mysql_command);
    $mysql_query->bindParam(':param_article_guid', $_GET["aid"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $mysql_query->bindParam(':param_member_id', $_SESSION["volow_member_id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $mysql_query->execute();

    while($mysql_row = $mysql_query->fetch())
    {
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_SESSION["volow_absolute_path"] . "/gallery/members/" . $_SESSION["volow_member_guid"] . "/" . $_SESSION["volow_channel_guid"] . "/" . $_GET["aid"] . "/". $mysql_row['file_name'] . ".png");

        if ($width > 650) { $width = 650; };
        if ($height > 271) { $height = 271; };
?>
<tr><td align="right" valign="top"><img src="<?php echo $_SESSION["volow_domain_name"]; ?>gallery/members/<?php echo $_SESSION["volow_member_guid"]; ?>/<?php echo $_SESSION["volow_channel_guid"]; ?>/<?php echo $_GET["aid"]; ?>/<?php echo $mysql_row['file_name']; ?>.png" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><hr></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: why dont you just store image details like title, img path when the img is uploaded. Then retrieving will be simple

Comment: sorry I didn't get you! I am already storing the path and no issue with it. I am talking about image title such as (valentine day pic) or (my happy birthday party)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a specific name for input files of each image. You need a unique identifier for each image for this purpose.

Assuming you have `file_id` field for each image, you can generate form elements as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="title<?=$mysql_row['file_id']?>" />
```

Then when handling form submission, you need to iterate over `$_POST` array to find out which image ids were submitted:

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
  if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'title') {
     $id = (int) substr($name, 5);
     $title = $value;
     $sql = "UPDATE imagetable SET title = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($title) . " WHERE id = " . $id;
     ...
     // run sql
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: what about saving it by just a button just like the StackOverflow Addcomment

Comment: That is AJAX. That is a different approach, you can investigate basic form submission with Jquery Ajax